# Filtering by List - Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

This query works, the `fullPath` field is a `List<String>`:

```
    KeyLookup lookup 
        = ofy().load().type(KeyLookup.class).filter("fullPath IN", key.getFullPath()).first().get();
```

The query above also fetch the entities having the same `String` elements in the `List<String>` as with `key.getFullPath()`, however it also fetches those entities having the same String in the list with additional **more** String in the list.

How can I filter only those Entity having the exact same elements in the list, like *"no more, no less"*

**Update:**

For example

One entity (say Object1) field fullPath contains:

- "One"
- "Two"
- "Three"

Another entity (say Object2) field fullPath contains:

- "One"
- "Two"
- "Three"
- "Four"

And key.getFullPath contains:

- "One"
- "Two"
- "Three"
- "Four"

Then the query above will return `Object1` and `Object2`, however what I need is that it only returns `Object2`

Comment: Do you mean that you get results for Strings that do not actually exist in the `fullPath` `List`?

Comment: I mean, I am comparing fullPath elements agains key.getFullPath elements (elements are Strings in a List<String>). fullPath may contain less items than with key.getFullPath, see my updated answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected since when comparing two lists in a query, what actually happens under the hood is that the datastore fires multiple queries for each of the values in the filter list. Thus, when you query for `Object2`, four queries are executed for each of the values in `Object2`. Since, `Object1` is a "subset" of `Object2`, it also matches the queries. This is the reason you get both `Object1` and `Object2`.

You can modify your queries to use the `AND` operator in order to force exact matching. So, you can have the following:

```
Query<KeyLookup> q = ofy().load().type(KeyLookup.class);
for (String f : key.getFullPath()) {
    q = q.filter("fullPath", f);
}
KeyLookup lookup = q.first().get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown operator 'AND'" for this one, it seems from the Objectify code, in the QueryImpl.java 'protected FilterOperator translate(String operator)' function, there is no AND operation, only IN

Comment: Note that this doesn't do _quite_ what the question asks - it doesn't provide a *exact* match, but it provides a *minimum* match.  For example, if there was an entity which had one/two/three/four/five, it would be returned because it matches the first four items.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't there is any way to do this at the datastore layer. You should tackle with it programmatically.

Comment: @stickfigure So it means the code above is just the same with using q.filter("fullPath IN", key.getFullPath()) ?

Comment: The code above is doing an `AND` for the Strings in the fullPath, while the `q.filter("fullPath IN", key.getFullPath())` does an `OR`. Thus, in my case you get all the entities that have at least **all** the strings in the fullPath, while at the `IN` case you get all the entities that have at least **one** of the strings in the filter list.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want an **exact** match (no more values, no fewer values), there is no "native datastore" way to implement this.  IN gets you an *or* operation, multiple calls to filter() gives you an *and* operation - neither of which are exact matches.  However, there are ways.

Option 1:  Join the list into a single indexed property

Concatenate all the items in the list into a single value and store that as a synthetic indexed property.  Maybe you need to normalize it depending on the significance of order or case.  Query on that property, not the list property.

This will only work if the concatenated value is guaranteed to fit under 500 chars.  Seems unlikely.  Instead you probably want...

Option 2:  Index and query on a hash of the list

1. Create a synthetic property which holds a hash of all the list values, something like `fullPathHash`.  It doesn't need to be cryptographically secure; MD5 is fine.
2. Whenever you update the list property, update the hash.
3. Index the `fullPathHash`; you don't need to index the list property.
4. When you query for a list of items, query on the hash.  Since there might be collisions, do a post-query check to make sure the lists are equal and skip any false positives.

Comment: Right, actually I implemented a 'String raw' field that represents a String value of the List. And during OnSave the List is saved as raw String...

Comment: So I have two options now, the raw key and the List filtering code by @thanos-makris